# Im getting reset on every http/s session after removing windivert64.sys and reboot

Tags: windows, filter, driver

I installed netspark on my computer and tried to remove it by removing every file and registery belongs to the program and windivert64.sys
Now Im getting reset for every http/s session, what can I do?
How can I find the driver that sends the reset?

I have win10

Answer (score 0):

After I tried to manually search the services list in services.msc I found nothing.
I tried to look for SysInternalSuite programs and found autoruns.
This tool shows every driver loaded on boot.
the list of the driver was very short and I easily found the driver by the publisher description.